# Setup Owin for Custom UserManager in Asp.Net Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, neo4j, owin, asp.net-identity-2

I'm using neo4j.AspNet.Identity for authentication of my website and I have the following class to connect to database that name is `GraphClientWrapper` and `Neo4jUserManager`.The `GraphClientWrapper` class is:

```
 using System;
using Neo4jClient;

/// <summary>A wrapper class to allow the GraphClient to be used within the OWIN framework (must implement <see cref="IDisposable"/>)</summary>
public class GraphClientWrapper : IDisposable
{
    public GraphClientWrapper(IGraphClient graphClient)
    {
        GraphClient = graphClient;
    }

    public IGraphClient GraphClient { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

and `Neo4jUserStore` class code is

```
public class Neo4jUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public Neo4jUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

    public async Task SetLastLogin()
    {
        //            Store.FindByIdAsync()
    }

    public static Neo4jUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<Neo4jUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var graphClientWrapper = context.Get<GraphClientWrapper>();
        var manager = new Neo4jUserManager(new Neo4jUserStore<ApplicationUser>(graphClientWrapper.GraphClient));

        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        //            manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<Neo4jUser>(manager)
        //            {
        //                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
        //                RequireUniqueEmail = true
        //            };

        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true
        };

        // Configure user lockout defaults
        manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = false;
        manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

        // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
        // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
        //            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<Neo4jUser>
        //            {
        //                MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        //            });
        //            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<Neo4jUser>
        //            {
        //                Subject = "Security Code",
        //                BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        //            });
        //            manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
        //            manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider =
                new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
        return manager;
    }
}
```

but for connecting to the database,I should follow these codes

```
var gc = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost.:7474/db/data"));
gc.Connect();
var graphClientWrapper = new GraphClientWrapper(gc);
var manager = new Neo4jUserManager(new Neo4jUserStore<ApplicationUser>(graphClientWrapper.GraphClient));
```

and the problem is I don't know how to setup owin to use my custom UserManager. Can anybody help to setup owin?